# Prophecy - Expect that no method will be called on an object

Tags: php, testing, mocking, phpunit, prophecy

right now I'm using the following code in PHPUnit to expect that no method is called on a mock:

```
$object = $this->createMock(ClassA:class);
$object->expects($this->never())->method($this->anything());
```

So far I haven't found a way to achieve the same result in Prophecy. I only have been able to test assumptions on specific methods so far and not on all methods like in the sample above.

Currently I'm using the following custom assertion to test whether no method has been called. Prophecy's ObjectProphecy exposes a method to get all calls to a specific function so I'm using reflection to get all methods on a class and than each call for each method. If the array of calls is empty afterwards, I know that no method has been called. The method now looks like this:

```
public function assertNoMethodHasBeenCalled(ObjectProphecy $prophecy, string $className)
{
    $methods = get_class_methods($className);

    $calls = [];
    foreach ($methods as $method) {
        $reflectionMethod = new \ReflectionMethod($className, $method);
        $numArgs = count($reflectionMethod->getParameters());
        $calls = array_merge(
            $calls,
            $prophecy->findProphecyMethodCalls(
                $method,
                new ArgumentsWildcard(array_fill(0, $numArgs, Argument::any()))
            )
        );
    }

    $this->assertEmpty($calls);
}
```

It's working for my limited sample size so far but I'm not happy with it. I feel like there should be an easier way to achieve the same result.

Comment: Could you explain why you have to check this? Maybe a little example would help.

Comment: @PhilipWeinke I have a function that updates an object and I'm trying to make sure that when a certain condition is met, the object is not touched (=> none of it's setters are executed)

Comment: Since you talk about setters, it sounds like it is some kind of data object. You might just pass in the real object instead of a mock and assert that it was not changed.

Comment: Great solution, thanks! Didn't know object comparisons are so simple with PHPUnit. Based on some quick testing and googling assertEquals seems to do the job just fine. Way easier and (likely) more reliable solution than my call checker. Easier to understand for other people too ;)

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To my knowledge, there is no simple to achieve this with Prophecy.

Prophecy works differently from PHPUnit's mocks when it comes to expectations. As soon as you set up an expectation, every call to your mock that isn't a prediction or a promise, will fail the test. Given the following object prophecy:

```
$prophecy = $this->prophesize(ClassA::class);
$prophecy->methodA()->shouldNotBeCalled();

$objectA = $prophecy->reveal();
```

Both

```
$objectA->methodA();
```

and

```
$objectA->methodB();
```

will fail the test.

So, when you don't set up any expectations, you have to check for calls manually like you did.

Comment: Thanks for the examples and clarification! I guess I'll just leave it as it is then because I only have a few cases so far where this is needed. I might add some tests for my assertion method to make sure it really works as expected.